# Interpetations of Number Theory into ZF and effective enumerability of ZF.

Tags: logic

I am currently reading Enderton's book "A Mathematical Introduction To Logic" and in the chapter for first-order logic it's mentioned that Zermelo-Frenkel set theory is effectively enumerable while number theory (In the book by that it's meant the theory of the structure with universum $\mathbb{N}$, functional symbols for successor, addition, multiplication, exponentiation, a constant symbol for zero and a predicate symbol for the less than relation $(\mathbb{N};0,S,+,\times,E,<)$. ) is not.

Now considering the fact that we could define the set of natural numbers in ZF along with the necessary functions/relations that will correspond to $(\mathbb{N};0,S,+,\times,E,<)$ (let's call this structure $\mathfrak{N}$) then we could define interpretation $\pi$ of Number Theory into the consequences of the ZF axioms (let's denote this set with $A_{ZF}$)  . Now it's true that using this interpretation $\pi$ for every sentence $\phi$ in the language of $\mathcal{N}$ we could define a sentence $\phi^\pi$ such that :

$$ \phi \in \mathcal{Th}(\mathfrak{N}) \implies \phi^\pi \in \mathcal{Cn}(A_{ZF})$$

Where $\mathcal{Th}(\mathfrak{N})$ is the theory of $\mathfrak{N}$ and $\mathcal{Cn}(A_{ZF})$  are the consequences of $A_{ZF}$.

Now if the above interperation was faithful (such that $ \phi \in \mathcal{Th}(\mathfrak{N}) \iff \phi^\pi \in \mathcal{Cn}(A_{ZF})$) then we could use the procedure that effectively enumerates $\mathcal{Cn}(A_{ZF})$ to effectively enumerate $\mathcal{Th}(\mathfrak{N})$. From that there must exist a sentence $\phi$ in the language of $\mathcal{N}$ such that $\phi^\pi \in  \mathcal{Cn}(A_{ZF})$ and $\phi \notin \mathcal{Th}(\mathfrak{N})$ hence $\neg\phi \in \mathcal{Th}(\mathfrak{N})$, using the fact that $\mathcal{Th}(\mathfrak{N})$ is complete.

So finally my question is:
Assuming that my reasoning is correct (if not then where is the mistake that I'm making) then is there a way to find some such sentence that's false in number theory but can be interpreted in the language of set theory as a true sentence ( this looks very strange and paradoxical to me so I'm more inclined to believe that some of my reasoning is wrong)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, basically, is that different models of set theory have different "versions" of the natural numbers sitting inside them. These versions have wildly different properties - e.g. there is a model $W$ of ZF such that $\mathbb{N}^W$ satisfies "$ZF$ is inconsistent" (this is just Goedel's completeness and incompleteness theorems together), while the "actual" one (pardon a moment of Platonism :P) doesn't.

What ZF can prove about the natural numbers amounts to the facts that are common to all the versions-of-$\mathbb{N}$ of models of $ZF$ (this is again just the completeness theorem). Indeed, there is an r.e. theory $T_{ZF}$ in the language of arithmetic such that for all $\phi$ in the language of arithmetic, we have $$T_{ZF}\vdash\phi\iff ZF\vdash\phi^\pi,$$ that is, $T_{ZF}$ is the "arithmetical content" of $ZF$. We do have $T_{ZF}\subseteq TA$ (here "$TA$" means "true arithmetic," the theory of the actual natural numbers); but $T_{ZF}$ is not *all* of $TA$ (in particular, it doesn't contain "$ZF$ is consistent").

Now, if $V$ is a model of set theory which is "correct about the natural numbers" - that is, $\mathbb{N}^V\cong\mathbb{N}$ - then indeed $TA$ is interpretable in $Th(V)$. But $Th(V)$ is much more complicated than $ZF$.

Comment: By the way, there's nothing special about getting $T$ from $ZF$: just enumerate the arithmetic consequences of $ZF$.

Comment: In the book an interpretation of theory $T_0$ into a theory $T_1$ is defined as interpretation $\pi$ of the language of $T_0$ into $T_1$ such that $\phi \in  T_0 \implies \phi^\pi \in T_1$. Using this definition my incorrect assumption was that such interpretation existed in the first place between the two theories while in fact we are making just interpretations of the language of number theory into set theory and for any such interpretation number theory will never be subset of the arithmetic part of set theory obtained through such interpretation. Is that correct?

Comment: @gcc-6.0 No, there is indeed an interpretation of arithmetic into set theory. The problem is that you need to distinguish between arithmetic *as an r.e. theory* (say, PA) and arithmetic *as the theory of some fixed structure* (say, $\mathbb{N}$). PA is interpretable in ZF; but $TA$, the theory of $\mathbb{N}$ ("true arithmetic"), is not.

Comment: It seems that I am using inappropriate terminology. By using the word number theory as stated in my question I meant exclusively the theory of that fixed structure (because that was the terminology used for that particular place in the book but I should've probably not used this at all because Number Theory usually has different meaning). I see no problem with interpretations of axiomatizable (hence effectively enumerable) theories such as PA being interpreted in ZF.

Comment: @gcc-6.0 Ah (and I see that you clarified this in your first paragraph - my bad, I missed that when I read the question). In that case, yes - there is no interpretation of $TA$ into $ZF$. In particular, any theory interpretable in an r.e. theory is r.e.

Comment: @gcc-6.0 I've heavily edited my answer to address your question better; let me know if this isn't an improvement, and I'll roll back. But I think this gets at things more cleanly (and doesn't accuse you of mixing models and theories, which was just my misreading of the question).